# Need help constructing radix tree c++

Tags: c++

I am constructing a radix tree in c++ using the huffman encoding. I was given an algorithm to follow and what I have written seems like it should work but it keeps crashing.

I am following this algorithm:

- Use a counter so that you know when the construction is complete (N chars require N-1 loops of this algorithm).
- Pass through the array of pointers, finding the two smallest frequencies of the 'root' nodes.
- Create a new node, storing the sum of the frequencies from those found in (b), storing the nodes found in (b) as its children, replace one of the pointers in the array with the address of this new node, and make the other 0.
- Use BSTDump to test your result. Note that depending on how you assign left and right and the 'new root', results will differ.

I am then attempting to test my results with this function:

```
void BSTDump(Node * r)
{
    static bool first = true;
    if (first)
    {
        cout << "Parent   Left   Right" << endl
             << "---------------------" << endl;
        first = false;
    }
if (r != 0)
{
    BSTDump(r->left);
    BSTDump(r->right);
    cout << setw(4) << r->theChar << r->freq;
    if (r->left != 0)
        cout << setw(8) << r->left->freq;
    else
        cout << setw(8) << '*';
    if (r->right != 0)
        cout << setw(8) << r->right->freq << endl;
    else
        cout << setw(8) << '*' << endl;
}
}
```

Here is the node construction:

```
struct Node
{
    double freq;
    char theChar;
    Node * left;
    Node * right;
};
```

And here is what I have written in the construction function which is what is not working correctly:

```
void ConstructTree(Node * &r)
{
Node * N[ASIZE];

for (int i = 0; i < ASIZE; i++)
{
    N[i] = new Node;
    assert(N[i] !=  0);
    N[i]->left = N[i]->right = 0;
    cout << "Enter the char and its frequency: ";
    cin >> N[i]->theChar >> N[i]->freq;
}

int Num = ASIZE;
while (Num > 1)
{
    // find two smallest.
    Node * p1;
    Node * p2;

    //p1->theChar = p2->theChar = N[0]->theChar;
    //p1->freq = p2->freq = N[0]->freq;
    //p1->left = p1->right = p2->right = p2->left = 0;

    p1 = p2 = N[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < ASIZE; i++)
    {
        if(N[i]->freq > p1->freq){

            //p2->theChar = p1->theChar;
            //p2->freq = p1->freq;
            //p1->theChar = N[i]->theChar;
            //p1->freq = N[i]->freq;

            p2 = p1;
            p1 = N[i];

        }
    }       
    // create a new node
    Node * sum = new Node;
    sum->freq = p1->freq + p2->freq;
    sum->left = p2;
    sum->right = p1;

    // update array N contents
    N[Num] = sum;
    delete sum;


    Num--;
}
// make certain that r knows where the root is
r = N[0];
}
```

Any thoughts on what the issue might be?

Comment: If you run your program in the debugger, you will discover what line caused the crash, and then you can work backwards from there.

Answer (score 0):

Hum...

```
// create a new node
Node * sum;
```

This is *not* creating a node. This is declaring an **uninitialized** pointer to a `Node`.

You are missing the `= new Node();` part here.

Answer (score 0):

Matthieu M. already spotted a bug: here another:

```
// find two smallest.
    Node * p1 = 0;
    Node * p2 = 0;
    p1->left = p1->right = p2->right = p2->left = 0;
```